# To create one Sharepoint page in 2016

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I need to create one page in Sharepoint 2016 that should have some columns (Single line, Multi line, Dropdown...).

Also requires if the user select one option from dropdown the other column gets active to perform. For example if i want to upload a PPT, i should choose PPT from dropdown and the column next to it should become active. While choosing any other option apart from ppt, the column next to it should remain inactive.

I hope I'm clear.

Comment: I can add/remove columns. Need to know this: if the user select one option from dropdown the other column gets active to perform. For example if i want to upload a PPT, i should choose PPT from dropdown and the column next to it should become active. While choosing any other option apart from ppt, the column next to it should remain inactive.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values in drop-down and if it contains multiple values and one is PPT and text-box next to it only activate when PPT selected then you can use following code,

```
<select id="myoption" onChange="changetextbox();">
<option>PPT</option>
<option>Other1</option>
<option>Other2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtppt" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function changetextbox()
{
  if (document.getElementById("myoption").value === "PPT") {
    document.getElementById("txtppt").disable='true';
   } else {
    document.getElementById("sdd").disable='false';
   }
}
</script>
```

If below don't work

```
document.getElementById("sdd").disable='false';
```

you can try

```
document.getElementById("sdd").disable='';
```